# Use console in another project

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, console

I have this weird problem where I *have* to set the console parameters like the *title*, *backcolor*, *forecolor*... and don't want to do it over and over. So I want to make a class that has a method that does it for me in **another project**. The *why* is not so important, I basically want to make common code to share between projects.

Something like :

```
// Console type project : 

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
          SetConsoleParameters(this.Console);
    }
}

// Class library

    public class SomeLibrary()
    {
       public Console SetConsoleParameters(Console console)
       {
          console.Title = "Nice title";
          console. // Etc...
       }
    }
```

I know you can't pass a static class like the console as a parameter and you can't access the console by with `this` but is it somehow possible to set things up like above ? (In a class that is not in the *Console Project*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the regular `System.Console`, even in a class library or whatever the utility project is.

Comment: I want the same Console. I'm in a different project. Sorry I updated a little late.

Comment: @phadaphunk: Same executable, same console.

Comment: Thats the point. It's not the same executable. There are many consoles I have like 30 different **projects** with their own individual executable. Now there is common code so I don't have redundant code. The part where I set the console is in a common code class library in a totally different **project**

Comment: @phadaphunk: The project doesn’t matter. If the library is compiled into your final executable or linked dynamically, it will still use the same console as the caller. Have you actually, you know, tried it?

Comment: Oh I get it. Can't believe I missed that.. Thanks a lot.